# join query in same table with condition

Tags: mysql, join, self-join

I have inserted both category and sub-category in same table.

id , name , mainCat ,

Here is the name of the category .If a user add a subcategory then i will add the parent category to maincat and sub category to the name.

but when come sorting i have sort Category wise.

can any one suggest me best query

Answer (score 0):

As long as you only have two levels of categories then a query like the following using a self-join will suffice. However, if you have many levels (i.e. a hierarchy) then the problem becomes a lot harder. See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ for more information.

```
SELECT p.Name, s.Name
FROM Categories s
LEFT JOIN Categories p ON s.mainCat = p.ID
ORDER BY p.Name, s.Name;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should post up some more details on what you are trying and the results that you are expecting.

Comment: i need to order my result.as i said i have my subcategory and category on the same field. so if i have a category (Sports) and sub category as ball.I want it to be listed or sorted after sports i disaplyed.i.e first sports and then sports->ball

Answer (score 0):

i tried with query a lot but finally i made it with php

```
$category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE mainCat = '' ORDER BY `name` ASC");

while($data = mysql_fetch_array($category)){
    $array[] = $data;
    $subCategory = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category WHERE mainCat ='".$data['name']."' ORDER BY `name` ASC");
    echo "SELECT * FROM category WHERE mainCat ='".$data['name']."' ORDER BY `name` ASC".'<br/>';
    while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($subCategory)){
        if($data2['mainCat']!=""){
            $array[] = $data2;
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have u try below:

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name
FROM tablename t1
LEFT JOIN tableName t2
ON t2.name = t1.mainCat
```

Comment: sorry friend :) this Query working only for a few category not for all.

Comment: where it fails?? will u please describe with realtime data